# Standard in writing triggers

Tags: trigger

i have written the trigger and class in the below way. Whether the trigger respects the bulk insert, and suggest me whether it has written as per the standards.  Can anyone please suggest on the below

**Trigger :**

```
trigger AlaisingfieldsBIBU_standard on Account (after insert,after update)   { 
   If(Trigger.isAfter)  {      
         If(Trigger.isInsert)  {
             for(Account rNew: Trigger.New){  
                  Aliasingfields.Alaisingfieldsview(rNew.id);  
            }    
        }
   }
}
```

**Class:**

```
Public class Aliasingfields {  
    Public static void Alaisingfieldsview(string id) {   
        list<Account> conacc = new list<account>();
        Id accid; 
        accid = id; 
        try      
        {    
            conacc = [select id,Name,Confidential__c, oname__c from account where id = :accid];
            for(account hideacc : conacc) {                                  
                if(hideacc.Confidential__c == true) {
                    hideacc.oname__c = hideacc.Name;
                    hideacc.Name = '**************';           
                    update hideacc; 
                }
            } 
        }                                        
        catch(Queryexception qe)   
        {   
            qe.getMessage();  
        } 
        catch(listexception le) 
        {   
            le.getMessage();  
        }  
    }
}
```

Comment: Avoid DML in for loop, it may hit the apex governor limits, you can check here      https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.salesforce_app_limits_cheatsheet.meta/salesforce_app_limits_cheatsheet/salesforce_app_limits_platform_apexgov.htm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of iterating through the `Trigger.new` and send only the `Id` to the handler class and do processing over there, its better to send the whole `Trigger.new` to the handler class and let it handle your business process over there.

So it will be like trigger hands over all its data and control to the handler and the handler will take it from there.

Instead of using after, i would user before triggers here. Because you do updates to the same accounts which just get inserted/updated. If you use before triggers, there is no need of extra updates.

There is no need for querying here as all the fields will be available in the `Trigger.new` itself.

**Trigger:**

```
trigger AlaisingfieldsBIBU_standard on Account (before insert,before update)   { 
    If(Trigger.isAfter)  {      
        If(Trigger.isInsert)  {                
            Aliasingfields.Alaisingfieldsview(Trigger.new);
        }
    }
}
```

**Handler Class:**

```
Public class Aliasingfields {  
    Public static void Alaisingfieldsview(List<Account> lstAccount) {   
        for(account hideacc : lstAccount) {                                  
            if(hideacc.Confidential__c == true) {
                hideacc.oname__c = hideacc.Name;
                hideacc.Name = '**************';           
            }
        }  
    }
}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: @perfect answer

Answer (score 1):

Your code has bulkification issue. Since you are calling your static method in a loop. And your static method contains SOQL and DML, it violates the rule of bulkification. Also, you put DML statement directly in a loop: update hideacc, which is very bad practice.

Optimized code: 
Trigger:

```
trigger AlaisingfieldsBIBU_standard on Account (after insert,after update)   { 
   If(Trigger.isAfter)  {      
         If(Trigger.isInsert)  {
             Aliasingfields.conacc = [select id,Name,Confidential__c, oname__c from account where id in :Trigger.New];
             for(Account rNew: Trigger.New){  
                  Aliasingfields.Alaisingfieldsview(rNew.id);  
            }    
        }
   }
}
```

Class:

```
Public class Aliasingfields {
    public static list<Account> conacc = new list<account>(); 
    private static List<Account> accountToUpdate = new List<Account>();
    Public static void Alaisingfieldsview(string id) {   
        list<Account> conacc = new list<account>();
        Id accid; 
        accid = id; 
        for(account hideacc : conacc) {                                  
            if(hideacc.Confidential__c == true) {
                hideacc.oname__c = hideacc.Name;
                hideacc.Name = '**************'; 
                accountToUpdate.add(hideacc);          

            }
        } 
        update accountToUpdate;
    }
}
```

Note I haven't add exception handling to the code. You should be able to handle that.

Comment: Thanks Lance for the reply. I am passing the id from the trigger to the class, querying with that and i am updating it. Following are the lines that i am performing in the code.

Comment: @user5558 Now you are having issues with bulkification. I will update my answer